# Modifying fullcalendar.io to show 'eventLimit' link for just 1 event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/141/) that will show event limit links when there is more then 1 event for a day. I'm trying to modify the .min file so that the limit link shows up when I have just 1 event on that day.

If I set the eventLimit value to 0, I still see a event in the day cell.

There is a line in the .min file that says

> eventLimit:!1

and I tried setting the value to 0 but it didn't change the event in the day cell to an event link like I want.

Can anyone help with modifying the .min file to show event limit links for just 1 event per day, instead of the normal event within the cell?

Here is some code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    //defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    editable: false,
    height: 174,
    eventLimit: 0,
    eventLimitText: function(numEvents) {
      return numEvents;
    },
    events: [{
        title: 'Event',
        start: '2017-09-18'
      } //,
      //{
      //title: 'Event',
      //start: '2017-09-18'
      //}
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: I don't think changing third party lib source code it a good option, especially when it is a .min file. Would you consider adding an empty event with no "title" but just "start" and leave the limit to be 1. It is a bit hacky though.

Comment: "Start"? I'm trying to get the number of events to be displayed in the center of each day cell. ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. I want it to look uniform and consistent so I want the eventLimit link for 1 event just like 2+ events. It doesn't seem like modifying the .min file should be that hard, or maybe modifying the js file, but I'm just not that experienced with doing it. Maybe just a pointer or two to help me out would be much appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you need , I guess what I'm saying is for every single day cell you can add an empty event. after that the first real event will trigger limit text to show up. And just need to make sure always display (numEvents-1). Does that make sense?

Comment: Another option would be to define your own "Custom Views" https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: oh I see what your saying...but looking at your other recomendation of a custom view, would that be possible with a custom view?

Comment: and, would I be able to orient the eventLimit link in the day cell to be centered horizontally and vertically and with a font-size with a custom view?

Comment: `eventLimit: 0` doesn't work because 0 is false-y and `eventLimit: false` switches the feature off. So fullCalendar sees these as equivalent. There's no support for what you want, so you're right you need to modify the source. But the .min.js file is not the original source - it's a compressed version (you can think of it like a compiled binary - technically not the same thing, but it's a version that's executable but not meant to be read by people). Edit the original fullcalendar.js instead - it'll be much easier to read and work out what to do.

Comment: You could also submit a feature request to the maintainer to add the feature you want. Or if you consider it a bug compares to the docs (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/) submit a bug report instead. Alternatively, if you patch fullcalendar.js yourself and it works, you could submit a pull request to get it brought into the main product. All of this is done via the project's GitHub repository, I believe.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show just the number of events on each day, not the actual events. I did this just recently here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012764/6089612, maybe it helps.