# jQuery FullCalendar > How to add a button (or link) to only days having events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using FullCalendar3.5.1.

I want to add one custom link to event day after all event for the day has been rendered.

If I use `eventAfterRender`, it display link after each event. So if there are 3 events it display 3 links while I need only one.

```js
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
    console.log(event);
    var new_description ='<br/><a href="javascript:dayDetails('+ '&#39;'
    +'template.html' + '&#39;'+',500,400,' + '&#39;'+event.start +'&#39;' 
    +',' + '&#39;'+ 'dayView' + '&#39;' +')">'
    + '<strong>Details</strong>'  + '</a>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    element.append(new_description); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach.  An alternative might be to try using `clientEvents` to retrieve all events and iterate over them.

**Updated** Jsfiddle to include working, positioned, links.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxr13oey/).

First, use the `eventRender` (or `eventAfterRender`) callback to flag each event as it is rendered:

```js
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    // Add a class to the event element
    element.addClass('event-on-' + event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

Next, use the `eventAfterAllRender` callback to iterate over the calendar after all events are rendered, and analyse each day:

```js
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    // This iterates over each visible day
    $('#calendar .fc-day.fc-widget-content').each(function(i) {
        // Fullcalendar includes a date data element on each day
        var date = $(this).data('date');

        // Now we can search for events on this day, using the date
        // and the CSS class we flagged events with
        var count = $('#calendar a.fc-event.event-on-' + date).length;

        // If there are some events on this day, you can add your link.
        if (count > 0) {
            $(this).append('<a class="foo" href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">Go</a>');
        }
    });
}
```

And lastly some CSS to position your links:

```js
.fc-widget-content {
    position: relative;
}

.foo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This is basically the approach used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012764/6089612), which might also be helpful.

Comment: count comes 0 all the time.

Comment: I had figured it out with dayRender: function(date, cell){
     var wbAddDetails = false;
     var dateString = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
      for(var i=0;i<allevents.length;i++ ){
       var currentevent=allevents[i];
       if(moment(currentevent.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == dateString){
        wbAddDetails = true; break;
       }
      }
      if(wbAddDetails){
       cell.append('DETAILS');
      }
     }

Comment: But problem is it appends on the top rather than the bottom

Comment: `it appends on the top` - if you mean they layout/styling of your link, yes you'll need to use some CSS to position it so it is not hidden by the events - eg absolutely positioned at the bottom of the day cell, or something like that.

Comment: @CFML_Developer did you get this working?  Does this help?

Comment: partially. I am trying solution provided by you. It was not working earlier becuse I didn't added that custom class. It is working now but the text I append is hyperlink actually but it is not clickable. Click event on this appended text does not work.

Comment: @CFML_Developer Hard to say without seeing your code, but it sounds like you have a click handler tied to DOM elements which exist on page load, but not DOM elements you add later.  You need to delegate to something that exists on page load, and filter your handler.  Check [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) section of jQuery event handler docs, and/or ask a new question :-) . Pls accept and upvote this answer if it answered your initial question!

Comment: nah, I just added a link on the fiddle you provided, it doesn't work there as well. So it is not due to any click handler for sure :)

Comment: Maybe a z-index issue?

Comment: Yes, that works. I had found an alternative. I solved by injecting those links as an event to my events data in backend code. But this too solve the problem. Please update the answer with fiddle code and I will accept the answer.